# How to manage undefined variables in a calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I have some predefined variables and some preexisted formulas(all multiplications). Formulas are calculating as expected besides when any of the variables are not defined.
Knowing that my formulas only handle multiplications I was thinking to give the value =1 to any undefined variable, in that way the calculation does break.

Is there any way to loop through the formulas, isolate the undefined variables and give them a value =1?

In the example below, ‘k’ is not defined and this calculation(kbd=k*b*d) is generating an error

```
#defined variables
a=10
b=5
c=3
d=6
e=7
f=2
g=9

#preexisted formulas
abc=a*b*c
fed=d*e*f
efg=e*f*g
kbd=k*b*d


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f9e3059809fc> in <module>
----> 1 kbd=k*b*d

NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you considered using a try statement?

Comment: @MohammadTehrani yes but how to? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using sympy which allows unevaluated variables, see [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/intro.html#the-power-of-symbolic-computation)?

Comment: `kbd=k*b*d` isn't a pre-existing formula, it's a python expression.  All variables in an expression need to exist, otherwise you get the NameError.  That's basic Python programming.

Comment: Using as @MohammadTehrani suggested a try-except clause seems a good idea. But I think it is in general important not to return a numerical bogus value, so perhaps it would be better to return None.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
a=10
b=5
c=3
d=6
e=7
f=2
g=9

formulas = ['a*b*c','d*e*f','e*f*g','k*b*d']

for form in formulas:
    variables = form.split('*')
    for v in variables:
        if v not in locals():
            locals()[v]=1
        
    eval(form)
```

Comment: It does what OP asked. But I it is likely a bad idea to implement.

Comment: @RonaldvanElburg can you please explain why it is a bad idea to implement?

Comment: @Verbamore In the future people (including you) are going to assume the function works. They might add an equation: 'x\*y\*z'. Trust that it works and if they mistype for example 'Z' for 'z' then there will be nothing to remind them that 'z' is missing. Then much later they see the output of  'x\*y\*z' and they don't understand it. They have put in 2 and 3 and 4 and still it produces 6. Turns out they wrote Z instead of z and the code never complained. In my view you want to be informed if something goes wrong.

Comment: So, if for some reason, you need this for robustness at runtime,  then at least you should generate a log message to send a reminder that you had to do something extraordinary to keep going. Personally I would prefer an early crash while testing.

Answer (score 0):

[Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/intro.html#the-power-of-symbolic-computation) is made for addressing your title **'How to manage undefined variables in a calculation'**. The variables can be defined as Sympy symbols:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k
# alternative of above line `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k=symbols('a b c d e f g k')`
a=10
b=5
c=3
d=6
e=7
f=2
g=9

abc = a*b*c 
fed = sympify(d*e*f) #you can convert an arbitrary expression to a type that can be used inside SymPy, based on https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html; not really necessary for these multiplication examples
efg=e*f*g 
kbd = k*b*d 
print(N(abc)) #based on https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html
print(abc)
print(fed) #based on https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html
print(fed.evalf()) #based on https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html
print(kbd)
print(simplify(kbd)) # based on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sympy/sympy_simplification.html
kbd # - or `simplify(kbd)` - as last line in a Jupyter cell, you'll see fancy `30k` with `k` in italics in out cell.
```

That last line won't do anything in a script though, yet the output will look fancy in a Jupyter cell using the Python kernel where you've run `%pip install sympy` in the cell above. (You can try that in the cell of a Jupyter notebook [here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master).)

##### Output from the print commands:

```bash
150.000000000000
84
84.0000000000000
30*k
30*k
```

Seen in 'Out' cell if run in Jupyter:

```bash
30
```

Comment: thank you for spending your time on this. I never heard before about sympy, I have to start reading about it. The solution that you are suggesting(from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k, to define the variable in this way) will be very time-consuming considering my real case(the example I provided is a simplified version of my real case). I have thousands of variables and hundreds of formulas. I need to build a loop. Also, considering my case I will need to give to undefined variable the value =1. It will not be accepted if I express it (referring to the example above) as 30*k.

Comment: The outcome has to be number

Comment: Oh I see your case is special so the solution with a variable present isn't going to work. Others ending up here given the broad title might benefit from sympy.